# Skip first element in every()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I want to run an every() function over a multidimensional array which checks if all the elements in a row are equal to 0. If so, they are removed.

However, I need it to skip the element at index 0 which will always be text. Is there anyway of doing it?

```
[
["BOOT", 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 180.0, 180.0, 665.0, 725.0, 725.0, 735.5, 1155.5, 1155.5, 1155.5], 
["IPP", 58.370000000000005, 58.379999999999995, 58.379999999999995, 140.38, 1073.975, 1184.5769999999998, 1724.927, 2086.9438, 2458.2437999999997, 4445.6398, 6067.0398, 6773.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999], 
["PPP", 1.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 135.0, 135.0, 135.0, 189.95, 231.54999999999998, 231.54999999999998, 556.5500000000001, 556.5500000000001, 806.5500000000001], 
["Rental", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
["State owned", 26.116000000000003, 166.116, 169.014, 226.663, 226.663, 345.66300000000007, 524.963, 564.763, 567.4150000000001, 614.4150000000001, 989.4150000000002, 1079.415, 1099.415, 1119.815, 1119.815]
]

   function removeZeros (array) {
     return array.filter(function(arr) {
       return !arr.every(function(elem) { 
        return elem === 0 
       })
     })
   }
```

In this case, the row that has 'Rental' at index 0 will be removed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could `slice(1)` before the every?

Comment: If you want to keep the same array you could `splice(0,1)` before every?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument passed to the `every` method off of the array is the `index`. You could check if the `index` is 0, and always return `true`. For example:

```
[1, 0, 2, 3].every((elem, index) => { 
   if (index === 0) { 
     return true;
   } 
   return elem === 0; 
}
```

In this way, the first element is never really considered in the truth test.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter out the **String**.

```js
const a = [
  ["BOOT", 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 180.0, 180.0, 665.0, 725.0, 725.0, 735.5, 1155.5, 1155.5, 1155.5],
  ["IPP", 58.370000000000005, 58.379999999999995, 58.379999999999995, 140.38, 1073.975, 1184.5769999999998, 1724.927, 2086.9438, 2458.2437999999997, 4445.6398, 6067.0398, 6773.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999],
  ["PPP", 1.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 135.0, 135.0, 135.0, 189.95, 231.54999999999998, 231.54999999999998, 556.5500000000001, 556.5500000000001, 806.5500000000001],
  ["Rental", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  ["State owned", 26.116000000000003, 166.116, 169.014, 226.663, 226.663, 345.66300000000007, 524.963, 564.763, 567.4150000000001, 614.4150000000001, 989.4150000000002, 1079.415, 1099.415, 1119.815, 1119.815]
]

function removeZeros(array) {
  return array.filter(function(arr) {
    return !arr.filter(e => typeof e !== 'string').every(e => e === 0)
  })
}

console.log(removeZeros(a))
```

You could just make the **String** a valid condition

```js
const a = [
  ["BOOT", 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 180.0, 180.0, 665.0, 725.0, 725.0, 735.5, 1155.5, 1155.5, 1155.5],
  ["IPP", 58.370000000000005, 58.379999999999995, 58.379999999999995, 140.38, 1073.975, 1184.5769999999998, 1724.927, 2086.9438, 2458.2437999999997, 4445.6398, 6067.0398, 6773.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999],
  ["PPP", 1.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 135.0, 135.0, 135.0, 189.95, 231.54999999999998, 231.54999999999998, 556.5500000000001, 556.5500000000001, 806.5500000000001],
  ["Rental", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  ["State owned", 26.116000000000003, 166.116, 169.014, 226.663, 226.663, 345.66300000000007, 524.963, 564.763, 567.4150000000001, 614.4150000000001, 989.4150000000002, 1079.415, 1099.415, 1119.815, 1119.815]
]

function removeZeros(array) {
  return array.filter(function(arr) {
    return !arr.every(e => e === 0 || typeof e === 'string')
  })
}

console.log(removeZeros(a))
```

Or do something that's not really effective (but uses `reduce()`, and that's *cool*):

```js
const a = [
  ["BOOT", 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 180.0, 180.0, 665.0, 725.0, 725.0, 735.5, 1155.5, 1155.5, 1155.5],
  ["IPP", 58.370000000000005, 58.379999999999995, 58.379999999999995, 140.38, 1073.975, 1184.5769999999998, 1724.927, 2086.9438, 2458.2437999999997, 4445.6398, 6067.0398, 6773.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999],
  ["PPP", 1.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 135.0, 135.0, 135.0, 189.95, 231.54999999999998, 231.54999999999998, 556.5500000000001, 556.5500000000001, 806.5500000000001],
  ["Rental", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  ["State owned", 26.116000000000003, 166.116, 169.014, 226.663, 226.663, 345.66300000000007, 524.963, 564.763, 567.4150000000001, 614.4150000000001, 989.4150000000002, 1079.415, 1099.415, 1119.815, 1119.815]
]

function removeZeros(array) {
  return array.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c.filter(e => e === 0).length !== c.length - 1) {
      a.push(c)
    }
    return a
  }, [])
}

console.log(removeZeros(a))
```

Or you could just use the "old-fashioned way":

```js
const a = [
  ["BOOT", 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 180.0, 180.0, 665.0, 725.0, 725.0, 735.5, 1155.5, 1155.5, 1155.5],
  ["IPP", 58.370000000000005, 58.379999999999995, 58.379999999999995, 140.38, 1073.975, 1184.5769999999998, 1724.927, 2086.9438, 2458.2437999999997, 4445.6398, 6067.0398, 6773.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999, 7098.639799999999],
  ["PPP", 1.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 131.5, 135.0, 135.0, 135.0, 189.95, 231.54999999999998, 231.54999999999998, 556.5500000000001, 556.5500000000001, 806.5500000000001],
  ["Rental", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  ["State owned", 26.116000000000003, 166.116, 169.014, 226.663, 226.663, 345.66300000000007, 524.963, 564.763, 567.4150000000001, 614.4150000000001, 989.4150000000002, 1079.415, 1099.415, 1119.815, 1119.815]
]

function removeZeros(array) {
  const ret = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let sum = 0
    for (let j = 1; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      sum += array[i][j]
    }
    if (sum) {
      ret.push(array[i])
    }
  }
  return ret
}

console.log(removeZeros(a))
```